# EOFError() triggered when calling input() after using aioconsole.ainput()

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, input, python-asyncio

I am encountering a strange error with a mini game I have created as part of a quiz application I am building to run in terminal. The mini game requires processes to run asynchronously, so I defined two coroutines to create it: one that prompts for input (using `aioconsole.ainput()`, an asynchronous input function) and one that executes a loop until input is entered. The mini game works fine on its own (included it in another program I made where it ran smoothly) and executes without error in the current application I am building, but after the mini game has executed, whenever I call the normal `input()` function, I receive an EOF error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/[...]/quiz_game.py", line 449, in <module>
    quiz()
  File "/Users/[...]/quiz_game.py", line 433, in quiz
    prev_score = show_score(playerList,prev_score)
  File "/Users/[...]/quiz_game.py", line 375, in show_score
    input('Hit enter to continue.')
  EOFError
```

I am 99.99% certain that the error has to do with some residual effect of executing the mini game's code, probably a residual effect of using `aioconsole.ainput()` because the code worked fine before I added the mini game into it, and distinct calls of `input()` in different locations within the overall code have triggered this error.
Here's the code of the mini game:

```
async def getInput():
  global flag
  flag = False
  task = asyncio.create_task(loop())
  await aioconsole.ainput()
  flag = True
  await task
  return task.result()


async def loop():
  count = 0
  x = 20
  while not flag:
    count += 1
    print('Hit enter at 20:' + '#' * (count % (x + 1)) + ' ' * (x - count %
                                                                (x + 1)),
          end='\r')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
  return count


def minigame():
  print('\nScore 20 to get a powerup.')
  for i in range(1,4):
    print(f'---ATTEMPT {i}---')
    result = asyncio.run(getInput()) % 21
    print('Score:' + str(result))
    if result == 20:
      print('SUCCESS!!!')
      time.sleep(2)
      return
    else:
      print(
        random.choice([
          'I said 20, moron!', 'Can you not count?',
          'Tut, tut, tut. Such a disappointment.'
        ]))
      print('Try again\n')
  print('FAIL. You have exhausted your 3 attempts.')
  time.sleep(2)
```

**Short Description of Mini Game:**
The mini game displays an increasing number of hashtags until it hits twenty hashtags and then starts over at zero hashtags. If the user hits enter at exactly twenty hashtags, they win the game.

Anyways, any help that you could provide would be greatly appreciated!